# Displaying a ton of images on one page?

Tags: html, image

Is there any way to do this without bogging down a computer?

I don't know much of the innerworkings of computers and browsers, so I don't know what about a bunch of images on a page takes up so much cpu. My first thought was to hide the images that aren't visible on the page anyway. The ones that have been scrolled past or yet to be scrolled to.

I tried a sample jsfiddle with randomly colored divs instead of pictures, but just scrolling up and down through that makes my computer sound like it's taking off.

What is it about all the pictures that takes up cpu? Can it be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is generally not about the amount of bandwith it might save. It is more about lowering the number of HTTP requests needed to render a webpage.

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Performance_best_practices_in_extensions)

What takes time, when doing lots of requests to get small contents (like images, icons, and the like) is the multiple round-trips to the server : you end up spending time waiting for the request to go, and the server to respond, instead of using this time to download data.

**Less http requests = faster loading overall**

If we can minimize the number of requests, we minimize the number of trips to the server, and use our hight-speed connection better (we download a bigger file, instead of waiting for many smaller ones).

That's why CSS sprites are used.

For more informations, you can have a look at, for instance : [CSS Sprites: Image Slicing’s Kiss of Death](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites)

Other than this you can also use [lazy load](http://engineering.slideshare.net/2011/03/faster-page-loads-with-image-lazy-loading/)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm talking about after the images are cached. I also do not control the content.